# How to show admob ads at bottom of page with viewpager and drawerlayout

Tags: android, xml

i have a activity with drawerlayout and viewpager i want to show admob ads at bottom of page so that it the ads keep showing at the bottom heve while user swipes through the viewpager . like we see in any newsreading app
this is my detail.xml

```
    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <FrameLayout

        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


        </RelativeLayout>
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="id" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerlist"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />
    <!-- android:entries="@array/planets" -->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and

detail_fragment.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
                android:text="@string/desc" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move AdView inside RelativeLayout and use  `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`
to make it visible at the bottom of all view.

```
   <FrameLayout

    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

         <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="id" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: removing android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" is it visible?

Comment: it shows ad on top of the textview set in detailfragment

Comment: Try  adding this back android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" and add margin bottom to 20px

Comment: nope the problem seems with height and smart banner

Comment: did you try making RelativeLayout height to MatchParent?

Comment: i am tring out below code now the ads appear at top

Comment: did you add android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" ?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

Comment: <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

           
        </FrameLayout>
         <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

Comment: ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="id" >
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerlist"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />
    <!-- android:entries="@array/planets" -->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

Comment: but now ads appear over the content not the way i want it ie one below the other

Comment: You mean Over the content is it over the list View?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/sColorPrimary"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!-- activity view -->
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        app:context=".Form" >
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frameLayoutMain"
                android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayoutAds"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutAds"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="1dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
                <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                    android:id="@+id/adView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    ads:adSize="BANNER"
                    ads:adUnitId="id" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Also you can add AdView programmatically:

```
   ((RelativeLayout)findViewById( R.id.relativeLayoutAds)).addView(adView);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
            android:background="@color/background" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="AD_UNIT_IT"
            ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
            android:gravity="bottom" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
```

Comment: Can you provide any detail about the problem in the question, or how this helps?